# Create type definition for function returning the module itself

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There is a nodejs module that looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  init(arg1) {
    // ..
    return this;
  },
  // ..
};
```

I'm trying to write a definition file. It looks like this

```
declare namespace ModuleName {
  function init(smth: string): ModuleName;
}
export = ModuleName;
export as namespace ModuleName;
}
```

And it almost works. When I import it

```
const a = require('ModuleName');
```

VSCode understands that `a.init` is a function accepting one string argument. But I cannot make it to understand that the result has method `init` too that can be called. Namely

```
const b = a.init('smth');
b.init('smth2');
```

What is the right way to write a type definition in such case?

Comment: Do you have to import stuff by `require` instead of `import`?

Comment: @PrzemyslawJanBeigert I would prefer to keep it functional for plain nodejs, but event if I use `import` it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I found only method via interface, but not sure.

```
declare namespace ModuleName {

    interface IModuleName {
        init(s: string): IModuleName;
    }

    function init(s: string): IModuleName;
}

const m = require('ModuleName');
const a = m.init('a');
const b = a.init('b');
```

Or more short

```
interface ModuleName {
    init(s: string): ModuleName;
}

const m: ModuleName = require('./ModuleName');
const a = m.init('a');
const b = a.init('b');
```

Comment: It seems to work, but the module has about 20 nested functions, objects and classes. There should be a better way ... I hope.

Comment: Yes, I hope as well.